# trigger a children fuction from a parent undefined event

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm very new in React Native so forgive my lack of knowledge.

I would like to call a function inside a child but triggered by a parent's event (onScroll here).

```
return (
    <View
        ref={ref => { this.split = ref; }}
        "onParentScroll"={() => {
        this.split.measureInWindow((x, y, height, width) => {
            console.log('X : ' + x)
            console.log('Y : ' + y)
    })}}>
        {childrenWithProps}
    </View>
)
```

By the way I can't set an onScroll direcly on the parent scrollView.
My goal is having several of this component in a same scrollView.

Comment: My goal is to get the position of my children at all time so if there is an easier way doing it let me know ;)

Comment: I've seen this issue before but my problem here is that i can't send my onScroll to my child and i don't see what to do with that

Comment: Can you explain more why you want to do this? Or why chasing the Childs props is not enough?

Comment: I need to measure my child position each time my scroll view is moving in order to trigger another child event.
But i'll have several of these child in a same scrollView so I need they to be independent.

Comment: Maybe this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent

Comment: I'll try another way, i need to measure the position of several component every time the user scroll (it is always my <Trigger> custom component).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is to send a boolean state as a prop and switch it onScroll.

```js
  <ScrollView
     onMomentumScrollBegin={() => { this.setState({ scroll : !this.state.scroll });}}
 onMomentumScrollEnd={() => { this.setState({ scroll : !this.state.scroll });}}>
        <Trigger trig={ this.state.scroll }><Text>oui</Text></Trigger>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference to the parent as a prop to the child like so:

```
<ChildComponent parent={this} />
```

and from the child, you update the parent's state, passing the a reference to the child itself like so:

```
this.props.parent.setState({ child1: this });
```

and finally, in the parent, you handle the updated information according to your needs, like so:

```
this.state.child1.callAnyMethod();
```